# grocery list app

Tags: windows

I do not have a smart phone, nor do I have a computer in my kitchen or anything elaborate like that. I would simple like recommendations on any applications that others **have found to be useful** for keeping recipes and printing out grocery lists.

Comment: a small notebook and a piece of paper stuck to the fridge with a magnet ? I mean, OneNote is a bit of overkill for bread, butter, 20 dkg of salami and 10 dkg of Gorgonzola cheese ... :)

Comment: You are pretty much right. I am wondering if anyone else has found luck with software, that is if it saves time.... I like to cook, a lot at that. And writing lists is actually something that could be automated, maybe. But in reality paper and pen is probably way more effecient than software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad and a good directory/file structure.

Seriously, I have tried everything in the past, but nothing works as well!

At any one moment, I have about 6 notepad windows open (which can become annoying, so thinking of switching to a multi-tabbed variant), but I find this very good - fast to open, prints well - works the way I want it to!

Comment: I'd grab Notepad++ (has tabs and lots more) if you go this way.

Answer (score 1):

For recipes, I use e-mail. One e-mail per recipe, name in the title, can contain text, URL, and images, easy to forward to friends, can all be filed in a folder/label, and available from multiple locations and devices. Hard to beat, really!

For grocery lists, I tend to use google sticky notes and todo-list gadgets that reside on my personalized google home page. Again the availability from both home and work is quite a considerable factor.

If I were to use a local application, check out [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/). It is free, open source and acts as a well organized collection of little texts. It supports basic rich text like bold, italic, but does not allow to put in pictures, although URLs are possible.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Allrecipes.com](http://allrecipes.com) to organize my recipes, find new recipes, and make grocery lists.  You can create private recipes only viewable to you, as well as public recipes that anyone can share and rate.  Of course, you can also add other people's public recipes to your "Recipe Book," rate them as you try them out, and categorize your favorite recipes however you like.  There's not much sense in fumbling around trying to bend general-purpose software to your will when there's already a domain-specific solution that was built from the ground up do exactly what you need.

One of my favorite features of Allrecipes.com  is that many of the recipes have been rated by hundreds of other users, and that they also often provide additional preparation tips.  Another handy feature is a converter which allows you to enter the number of servings you want to produce, then shows you the modified list of ingredients.

You can also use the website to build a shopping list from selected recipes, which you can then print out and take along with you to the store.

Comment: Can you print a composite list of ingredients for certain recipes that you want to cook for that week?

Comment: Yessirree, it will combine all the common ingredients for your recipes into a single line item for each ingredient.  It also categorizes the ingredients by grocery department (e.g., baking supplies, dairy).  You can also manually add items from a list if, for example, you know you're running low on Rice Krispies for breakfast; and you can write in your own items if you need to get something that AllRecipes didn't include in their list of possible grocery items.

Answer (score 0):

**[Shopping List](http://www.acutesoftware.com.au/shopping.html)** - Quickly make your shopping lists and print them sorted by aisle.

Simply make a shopping list by dragging items from the 'supermarket shelves' into your current weekly list - edit the quantities you need and print it.

[image]

it doesn't get much easier, except you still have to go to the supermarket yourself ;)

more of the same here: **[SHOPPING - FREE SOFTWARE](http://freeware.intrastar.net/shopping.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [Remember The Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com). It's very powerful and customizable so it can be used for Work, Home, Grocery, etc. One of the best applications I've ever used.

Answer (score 0):

I use OneNote for all of my recipes and lists.  If you copy stuff from the web, it includes a link to the original site, which is handy for tracking down information.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a recipebook which is html & javascript. This works ok for me because, I am able to copy the recipebook to any folder or send it to people without changes for any OS.

My biggest problem with it is that I was a beginner at HTMLwhen I wrote it and I didn't standardize the code so getting the data to everywhere I need it to be can be cumbersome.

The recipebook contains over 500 recipes, with the javascript being used for the search.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw in my own method too (I like to cook a lot of things). Google docs, with a link to each recipe if there is one. It is just line delimented with categories like lunch. I then write down a recipe and usually know the ingredients by recipe alone, but sometimes I forget things and go back :(.